# How can one add Git Submodules to a Forked Repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

I was looking at this explanation on the use of Submodules within GIT (also, in my case, I am using Gitlab to store code and not github).

I was reviewing instructions mentioned here:
LINK 1: [Working With Submodules](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules)

I was looking at this item as well:
LINK 2: [Gitlab Submodules](http://%20https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/git_submodules.htm)

In LINK 1, it seemed to say that that the Main Repository (Parent) and Sub Repository (Submodule) are just regular repositories within the Git system.

In the picture below, I would like (as an example) to have forks of each repository (for development, testing and production).

[image]

Each level would be (for the Parent : TEST is a FORK of PROD, DEVL is a FORK of TEST):

```
testme.com:DEVL/restapi-field.git
testme.com:TEST/restapi-field.git
testme.com:PROD/restapi-field.git
```

Each level would be (for the Submodule: TEST is a FORK of PROD, DEVL is a FORK of TEST ):

```
testme.com:DEVL/submoduleOne.git
testme.com:TEST/submoduleOne.git
testme.com:PROD/submoduleOne.git
```

According to LINK 2, one should use a file called `.gitmodules`

The thing is, `.gitmodules` would be defined differently in the parent (based upon the group it is in). Again, see picture.

How could one implement this?

I have seen some cases where one would just define all files needed (example):

```
.gitmodules.development
.gitmodules.test
.gitmodules.production
```

and then each level (i.e. development, test, production) would work with the file that was most applicable to it.

Jenkins is also being used in this scenario. Should I make the following job in Jenkins whereby:

1. Jenkins pulls down the correct Parent repository (either development, testing or production)
2. Copy the correct corresponding `.gitmodules` into the repository
   ( ex: cp .gitmodules.development  /.gitmodules )
3. Run an Update to get the most recent versions (i.e. something like)

   - git submodule sync --recursive
   - git submodule update --init --recursive
4. Contiue processing with the code (i.e. compiling it, creating a lib, etc.)

Any other options that one could consider?

TIA

Comment: Different environments should not be represented by separate copies of a repository, in my opinion. Instead, use long-running branches if you need to (a `production`, `development` and `test` branch. Check out the GitLab blog post on 'GitLab Flow' which talks through the concept of using stable branches and tags - https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/

 Also, steer clear of submodules - they will only cause lots of pain.